# pam_cracklib reports bad password correctly but pam_unix module STILL changes the password

Tags: pam, cracklib

I am currently trying to use `pam_cracklib` which properly fails according to my debug.log but even though it is setup as a `password requisite` entry in my PAM config file, it still falls through to the next `pam_unix` module which allows for a password change. Why is it allowing for a password change?

I am executing a login driver application through `sudo`, which is the only way I know how to authenticate.

Here is my PAM config file (named `/etc/pam.d/validate`):

```
auth  required    pam_env.so
auth  required    pam_tally.so onerr=fail deny=3
auth  sufficient  pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass 
auth  requisite   pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth  required    pam_deny.so

account  required    pam_unix.so
account  required    pam_tally.so
account  sufficient  pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account  required    pam_permit.so

password requisite   pam_cracklib.so debug retry=3 minlen=14 lcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1
password sufficient  pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password required    pam_deny.so

session  optional    pam_keyinit.so revoke
session  required    pam_limits.so
session  [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session  required    pam_unix.so
```

I invalidate my user password forcing them to change it:

`# chage -d 0 <user>`

when I run the custom application using `sudo` my `/var/log/debug.log` produces the following.

```
pam_unix(validate:account): expired password for user mike (root enforced)
pam_cracklib(validate:chauthtok): bad password: it is WAY too short
pam_unix(validate:chauthtok): password changed for mike
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `sudo` runs your commands as root.

If you check `man pam_cracklib` you'll see the following

```
   enforce_for_root
       The module will return error on failed check also if the user
       changing the password is root. This option is off by default which
       means that just the message about the failed check is printed but
       root can change the password anyway. Note that root is not asked
       for an old password so the checks that compare the old and new
       password are not performed.
```

So, what you need to do is change your `pam_cracklib.so`line to say

```
password requisite   pam_cracklib.so debug retry=3 minlen=14 lcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 enforce_for_root
```

---

Having looked at the pam_cracklib.so source it does the following at line 804 (on Fedora 20 anyhow)

```
  if (getuid() || options.enforce_for_root || (flags & PAM_CHANGE_EXPIRED_AUTHTOK))
```

So, it checks the real UID of the caller and enforces the change or not depending on whether the the real UID is 0.

So, you should simply be able to setuid your binary and make sure root owns it, then it will be able to change password and enforce the cracklib decision. setuid'ing your binaries only sets the effective uid to 0, not the real one.

Comment: I did a `man` on my RHEL system since it did not work for me, and apparently that is not one of my supported options :(  Is there another way to authenticate without `sudo`?  I would prefer not to use `sudo`.  Whenever I try it always fails without those permissions.

Comment: I cant tell you that without knowing what your application does. Try.

Comment: Is it a test you wrote yourself?

Comment: It's amazingly straightforward.  It's a test to change the password using PAM.`value = pam_start("validate", user, &conv, &pamh);` `if(value == PAM_SUCCESS) { password = pass;`   `value = pam_acct_mgmt(pamh, 0);`  `if (value == PAM_SUCCESS || value == PAM_NEW_AUTHTOK_REQD) { password = pass;`   `value = pam_chauthtok(pamh, PAM_SILENT);` `}  }  }`

Comment: If I could get my `pam_cracklib` source code on my system I might be able to add the `enforce_for_root` option from [pam_cracklib](http://fossies.org/dox/Linux-PAM-1.1.8/pam__cracklib_8c_source.html). Unfortunately I can't do that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an alternative which should function.